# Delphi mobile UIActionSheet cross-platform equivalent

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe6

Does anyone know if there is a cross-platform method available in Delphi XE6 for performing what is called the UIActionSheet in iOS? That is, a popup panel that contains several custom buttons. On iOS, for example, this can be seen when pressing the Flag or Reply buttons on an email, where it pops up further options such as Reply, Reply All or Forward.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

However, I need it to be cross-platform so an approach that works for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's posible, Please Look http://www.fmxexpress.com/native-progress-dialogs-for-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/

It's native

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this component set but thought it was more for progress dialogs, I had not spotted the ActionSheet parts.